# overloaded jar run with flags via cmd (like init, help etc)

Tags: java, jar

I would like to overload jar run with flags like init or help. Help would display what parameteres user need to pass and what they mean (im passing several run arguments when invoking jar via cmd). Init would initialize properties file (password etc). How I am supposed to approach that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like any  other Console Application....with the Command-Line. The `/?` tag (`AppName.jar /?`) would generally mean to display a short Command-Line help document presentation only. This help could be hard-coded but would be better if read in from a local text file or run from a batch file. Specific tags would be specific parameters for your application, for example,

```
MyAppplicationName.jar /pass:MyPassword /title:"A&B Company" /name:"Tom Jones"
```

Note that strings after the Command-Line tags which contain white-spaces are enclosed within quotation ("") marks. A single white-space must be between each Command-Line tag. Command-Line tags can be supplied in any order using the below demo code:

Here is a runnable demo which demonstrates:

```
public class CommandLineDemo {

    public final static String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    public final static java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;
    private String appTitle;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // App started this way to avoid the need for statics:
        new CommandLineDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            for (String arg : args) {
                String[] argParts = arg.split(":");
                switch (argParts[0].toLowerCase()) {
                    case "/?": case "/help":
                        displayHelp();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    case "/name":
                        this.userName = argParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "/pass":
                        this.userPassword = argParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "/title":
                        this.appTitle = argParts[1];
                        break;
                    // etc, etc, etc, ...
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Application Title: -> " + this.appTitle);
        System.out.println("User Name:         -> " + this.userName);
        System.out.println("User Password:     -> " + this.userPassword);
    }
    
    private void displayHelp() {
        // Apply your help mechanism here (whatever it will be)...
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Application Help:" + LS + "================");
        System.out.println("Any text after a command-line tag which contains one or more");
        System.out.println("white-spaces must be enclosed within quotation (\"\") marks." + LS);
        System.out.println("Command-Line Tags:" + LS + "==================");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-100s%n", "/title:", "The title for application (Company Name or whatever).");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-100s%n", "/name:", "The User Name     (required).");
        System.out.printf("%-12s %-100s%n", "/pass:", "The User Password (required).");
        System.out.println("*** More help would go here ***");
        System.out.println(LS + "<< Press ENTER to continue >>");
        String tmp = userInput.nextLine();
    }
}
```